# "Non white space characters cannot be added to content" when creating Linq XML document

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Ok so I'm caching a file in memory by doing

```
byte[] file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("test.xml");
```

Then later on I'm trying to create an xml document from that buffer like so:

```
System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(file);
System.Xml.XmlTextReader reader = new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(stream);
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument xPartDocument = new System.Xml.Linq.XDocument(reader);
```

But this fails creating document with the following exception:

> ```
> A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Xml.Linq.dll
>
> Additional information: Non white space characters cannot be added to content.
> ```

However 'reader' just looks wrong ie in the locals it has 'None' as the value:

- reader  {None}  System.Xml.XmlTextReader

Also the 'file' byte array variable has 11 bytes of what looks like header (I presume this is just txt file header?):

```
0x0393B148  58 35 59 71  X5Yq 
0x0393B14C  dc 67 01 00  Üg.. 
0x0393B150  ef bb bf 3c  ï»¿< 
0x0393B154  3f 78 6d 6c  ?xml 
0x0393B158  20 76 65 72   ver
```

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: That doesn't look like an XML file to me.

Comment: if you cut off the header does it work then? It's from an sql server isn't it? @Blindy it is an xml file it just has some gobledygook at the beginning

Comment: Actually that looks like a hex editor screen dump.  You can see the beginnings of the XML tag in the right-hand column, although the addresses are a bit of a mystery.

Comment: a text file doesn't generally have a header like that... I've no idea what you've got there... :) If you open test.xml in notepad (or similar plain text editor) does it work? Do XMl readers read it happily? Can it load in IE (a surprisingly useful but not 100% guaranteed quick and dirty test of XML files)?

Comment: The first *8* bytes are the header, by the looks of it - the next 3 bytes are a UTF-8 BOM. Where did you get this file from?

Comment: Be that as it may, @RobertHarvey, that file as it's written right now is not a valid XML document, hence his problem. In a very Heroes-esque manner, save the file, save the XML! (that sounded better in my head)

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I presume that is just viewing the byte array in debug mode or something. And I don't know for sure but I assume the addresses are the memory where that array is currently living. And the whole point of it is that the XML is there but with 11 bytes of some other garbage before it...

Comment: That would seem to be the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet does your head ever not store anything why do you know how a UTF-8 BOM looks like :)

Comment: @the_ajp: I couldn't have told you off the top of my head what it was - but I know it when I see it.

Comment: @JonSkeet: interesting. I've never seen that before. I guess probably because its a bit superfluous really. :)

Answer (score 6):

As noted in comments, the first 8 bytes look like they don't belong at the start of an XML file. The next three bytes are a UTF-8 BOM, which is fine. You should work out where those 8 bytes came from, and whether you should always expect them to be there.

If they'll always be there and you *want* them to be there, simplest way of fixing this is to just move the stream before reading:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(file);
stream.Position = 8;
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
```

Alternatively, without loading all the data first:

```
XDocument doc;
using (Stream input = File.OpenRead("test.xml"))
{
    input.Position = 8;
    doc = XDocument.Load(input);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi everybody thank you all to your input, the binary dump in my question is simply a dump from VS's memory dump window of the 'file' variable.

@Jon Skeet you actually kind of answered the question but by incident as the binary 8 byte header (or 11 bytes with the 3 byte UTF header) is perfectly fine.

The simple answer to my problem was that I was contructing the XDocument from the text reader rather than calling the static Load function on it. Doh!